# Catch exception from bound library

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have bound the Star Micronics SDK to my Xamarin application. My app randomly crashes though with the following error:

```
SIGABRT - 'PortException', reason: 'Native WritePort failed'
```

My bound method looks like:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface SMPort {

    //...

    [Export ("writePort:::")]
    Int32 WritePort (IntPtr writeBuffer, int offSet, int size);

}
```

And I call it using:

```
    private static void Print(NSMutableData commandsToPrint) {
        try {
            //...
            int count = printerPort.WritePort (test, 0, Convert.ToInt32(dataBytes.Length));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //...
        } finally {
            //Release the port
            SMPort.ReleasePort (printerPort);
        }
```

The Objective-C implementation of the original C library catches a PortException exception:

```
@try
{
    [starPort writePort:dataToSentToPrinter :totalAmountWritten :remaining];
}
@catch (PortException *exception)
{
    //...
}
@finally
{
    //...
}
```

How do I catch the same exception in my Xamarin App, so I can handle the exception and stop the app from crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Catching Objetive-C exceptions from managed code is not a supported scenario [1], and may sometimes work, and other times won't.

In your particular case easiest solution would be to wrap the third-party native library in another library (which you write yourself), which would translate the Objective-C exceptions into any other error-reporting mechanism (return an error code for instance).

So in C you'd have something like this:

```
int call_writeport (SMPort *starPort, void *dataToSendToPrinter, int totalAmountWritten, int remaining)
{
    @try
    {
        [starPort writePort:dataToSentToPrinter :totalAmountWritten :remaining];
        return 0;
    }
    @catch (PortException *exception)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and in C# you can bind this as a DllImport:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
static extern int call_writeport (SMPort port, IntPtr writeBuffer, int offset, int size);
```

and usage:

```
if (call_writeport (port.Handle, writeBuffer, offset, size) != 0)
    Console.WriteLine ("Writing to port failed");
```

My choice of writing a C method (and bind using a P/Invoke) is arbitrary, you could just as easily create an Objective-C class and bind that in your binding project.

[1] Apple strongly recommends against using Objective-C exceptions for anything but the most fatal scenarios, which is why it hasn't been a high priority for us to fix on our end.

Comment: Thanks Rolf. The writePort method actually returns an int, which I need access to. How would I handle this situation?

Comment: You can add an 'out' parameter to the function signature to return the error code as well.